# Como generar dos jpanel

Tags: java

tengo una duda como podria realizar dos JPaneles en una ventana, en una de ellas debo colocar figuras geometricas pero no entiendo como podria realizarlo, tengo mi codigo de las figuras pero no se, como podria adecuarlo para que en el lado derecho aparecieran mis figuras y en el izquierdo otra cosa como por ejemplo una suma, es decir que cada panel haga algo diferente

```
public class Dibujo extends JPanel {


public void paintComponent(Graphics cuadro1) {
    super.paintComponent(cuadro1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        Random r = new Random();
        Color randomColor = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));

        Random num = new Random();
        int numero,posicion,posicion1,numero2;
        numero = num.nextInt(100);
        posicion = num.nextInt(400);
        posicion1 = num.nextInt(400);

        cuadro1.setColor(randomColor);
        cuadro1.fillRect(posicion, posicion1, numero, numero);

        cuadro1.setColor(randomColor);
        cuadro1.fillRect(posicion, posicion1, numero, numero);



    }

}
```

}

Me podrian dar un ejemplo puede ser sencillo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un **JFrame** por defecto establece un Contenedor **'BorderLayout'** el cual organiza y redimensiona sus componentes para que quepan en 5 Regiones **'NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and CENTER.'**

---

Te voy a poner un ejemplo, en el cual la Clase Principal es un JFrame, y las otras dos clases son JPanel y colocaremos una de ellas en la zona Central del JFrame y la otra clase en la zona Izquierda u 'Oeste' de ese JFrame.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class DosDibujos extends JFrame {
    public DosDibujos() {
        setTitle("Paneles");
        setBounds(300, 300, 400, 350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.add("Center", new DibujoDer());
        this.add("West", new DibujoIzq());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DosDibujos().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DibujoDer extends JPanel {
    public DibujoDer() {
        this.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
}

class DibujoIzq extends JPanel {
    public DibujoIzq() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Texto Izquierdo");
        this.add(label);
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La clave está en estas 2 líneas..

```
this.add("Center", new DibujoDer());
this.add("West", new DibujoIzq());
```

Donde añadimos un panel a la zona central y otro panel a la zona izquierda.
También se podría añadir de esta manera con unas constantes ya predefinidas.

```
this.add(new DibujoDer(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.add(new DibujoIzq(), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tener dos páneles diferentes y agregar ambos en otro panel. Por ejemplo:

```
Dibujo panel1 = new Dibujo();

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.add(new javax.swing.JLabel("etiqueta en panel 2");

JPanel panelCentral = new JPanel();
panelCentral.add(panel1);
panelCentral.add(panel2);
```

Ahora ya tienes el panelCentral que adentro tiene dos páneles. Ahora que si quieres ponerlos uno arriba de otro o uno al lado de otro requieres aprender de Layouts.